# Where are logs for couchdb on iriscouch?

Tags: couchdb

I'm using CouchDB on iriscouch.com.

I have made a database, which I have filled with some data. I'm running a map and a reduce function to filter out some items, but it doesn't work. Since console.log isn't working I'm trying to use the log() function CouchDB supplies. But I can't find the log files. I have found the path in the config, but thats the file path on the server, and I only have access to futon (I think).

Is there any request I can make to read the logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your.iriscouch.com/_log

if you want to reach further back in the log use the bytes=x querystring, eg

your.iriscouch.com/_log?bytes=2000

Also, you will need to be logged in as an admin to access the above urls.

Comment: Can't believe I just found this, awesome.